# How to run multiple spark jobs parallel on yarn with cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

For example , when I submitted the first job to yarn cluster , the job is running ,and then submitted the second job, the second job state never run until the first job completed either success or fail.

Is there any way to run multiple spark jobs parallel on yarn with cluster mode?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about your queues settings. 
If you don't explicitly specify your job queue using `--queue QUEUE_NAME` yarn launches it in default queue, otherwise (if you add parameter `--queue system` while submitting your job in specified queue).
You can configure queues (create new, set max number of apps!, split resources between queues etc) in YARN/Configs/Advanced/Scheduler (I'm using Ambari), parameter `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-applications`.

Also read https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

Comment: i already set yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-applications to 10 ,it still does not work

Comment: @jasonzhang, for which queue? Try yarn.scheduler.capacity.system.maximum-applications to 10 and add spark-submit parameter `--queue system` while launching your apps. Make sure you have enough resources to run multiple jobs

Comment: @jasonzhang and check your system queue scheduling policy, it should allow to launch multiple jobs (try fair)